# opencart default language selection

Tags: php, opencart

I have set my default language from admin panel to Persian.

Now, every module uses persian language directory by default.

Thought there is one module that still persists in using English as its language. While I have set the translation in corresponding directory in language/persian.

My question is that how can I force the module to use the language/persian instead of language/english?

Here is the beginning of the module's Controller that fetches the language file:

```
$this->language->load('module/trackorder');

        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
        $this->data['back'] = $this->url->link('common/home');
.....
```

Comment: It looks like a third party extension/module, isn't it? In this case, please, ask for support to it's developer(s).

Answer (score 0):

Already checked if `catalog/language/persian/module/trackorder.php` exist, and isn't in english? there is only a way to force another language, instancing a new language object, as follows:

```
$my_language = new Language('language_directory');
$my_language->load('path-to/language-file'); // without extension
$my_language->get('translation_index');
```

example:

```
$my_language = new Language('english');
$my_language->load('module/cart');
echo $my_language->get('heading_title');
// this print 'Shopping Cart'
```